# If humans all disappeared would it be good for the environment?

Tags: environment, climate, natural-disasters

**SIGNIFICANTLY UPDATED**

I've seen similar questions, but not the answer I'm looking for (kinda - obviously all answers are...well...answers).

Yes, I am aware that what I'm asking is really multiple questions, but there is a single focused one:

**What would happen to the natural environment if something like the Rapture happened - all of a sudden, every person on earth just disappeared?**

Basically, since humans have existed, we have made changes to the natural environment to suit us, whether it's 'cavemen' enlarging existing caves to make them habitable to building enormous hydroelectric dams to generate power and provide a stable water supply.

The majority of these changes have either been neutral or bad for the environment. I'm not talking about 'morally' bad as such, more that they have altered the natural environment in ways that have had deleterious effects on the non-human flora and fauna sharing our environment. Depending on your POV, maybe those are morally bad.

So I'm wondering whether, if humans suddenly disappeared, the earth would eventually revert to a similar state prior to humans or whether the changes we have wrought are such that either the environment will never right itself or indeed, that some of the changes that we have currently implemented would, as they 'decay' without constant input from humans, cause even greater environmental issues.

Like I said above, this isn't a discussion of good and evil - it's a musing on the effects on the environment if humans disappear. So when I say "good" and "bad" in the examples below, I mean purely from the POV of environmental effects.

Some examples:

Short-term (minutes/hours) obviously lots of cars would crash (some of which would catch fire and maybe start wildfires), planes would drop out of the sky etc. So that's bad for the environment - a bunch of fires and polluting smoke. But obviously all those cars would also immediately stop pumping out pollution, so that's good for the environment. In the developing world, home fires (charcoal, firepits etc.) would go out, and that's also good.

Medium-term (days/weeks), fossil-fuel plants would shut down (possibly in an orderly automated manner?) which would clearly reduce pollution - good. Likewise factories etc. All probably good. But oil tankers would run aground and spill their contents (bad), but in the grand scheme of the oceans how bad is that - oceans are very big, so over time, the oil would be absorbed and dissipate.

Longer-term (months/years/decades) is where things get tricky. All those cars/trains etc. would rust and spill toxic chemicals (fuel, oil etc.) into the environment. That's bad, but probably not too bad, even for how many there are. But what about oil wells - do they just keep pouring oil into the ocean or wherever?

How quickly would things like hydroelectric dams break down? Hundreds of years? Is that a net good or a net bad? I mean, we dammed a river, so it would be setting things 'right', but at the same time, if a dam breaks catastrophically, that's catastrophic.

Finally, the biggie - nuclear stuff.

Nuclear plants would...what? Shut down in the absence of human control? Would the cooling water eventually evaporate, leading to thermal meltdown? How bad is that? What about nuclear submarines? Nuclear weapons would eventually rust etc. - could that lead to nuclear leaks?

Basically, aside from the nuclear concerns (and maybe offshore oil wells), I'm guessing it would probably be a net good for the environment if we all suddenly disappeared. But how bad is the nuclear concern?

What else have I not thought of?

Comment: Without defining good and bad this is unanswerable. It's also incredibly broad. Could you re-read the [ask] section of the [help], then [edit] this into a question which can be answered without resorting to opinion, and can have a single defined "best answer"  *in advance of it being answered* aaand doesn't require a book or more to do so. Perhaps start by telling us what your objectives are.

Comment: When I read the original question I thought there was a clear good defined. When they say planet, I think they meant environment. The planet as a whole is gonna be fine regardless, but they seem to care about the biosphere and natural resources and such on the surface of the planet, so I did an edit towards what I think they cared about.

Comment: From the perspective of the planet, all of this is super-short-term. We could vanish into heaven, our buildings decayed by rain and covered over by dirt, every vestige of our existence plowed under, and Yellowstone still won't have made up its mind whether it's going to erupt or not.

Comment: @NepeneNep: To say that something is good or bad requires a scale of values, which requires a thinking subject. Propertly speaking nothing is good or bad for the environment, because the environment is not a thinking subject. Stuff may be *perceived* as good or bad for the environment *by humans*. (Or, actually, by *some* humans -- there is never unanimity about [what is good and what is bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SINyUrWeu-Q).) If all humans are dead, then nothing is good and nothing is bad.

Comment: I have a video wondering exactly what would happen to the world, but alas it's in French only and there's no reliable translation. Point is, this video explains it in 360s, and they do take shortcuts. This means that what you're trying to eat is likely too big. I'd suggest to focus on one specific insfrastructure failure (e.g. : nuclear plants, chemicals factory...), or environment (big cities, U.S. farms...).

Comment: I don't think it would be appropriate for stack exchange to take a particular moral stance on whether good or evil existed. That said, if you feel it's important, feel free to open a meta worldbuilding question about whether our formal policy is that good and evil don't exist outside humans, moral realism is wrong and that morals aren't from nature. Anyway, enough people understand what good for the environment mean that it's a comprehensible question.

Comment: First define good for the environment  just once .. your examples are not a definition they are opinions on a group of random things with no justification offered for 'why' they are 'bad for the environment' and as such don't provide a definition that can be applied to any other things not listed .. plus the rule is **one** question per question & *(without the definition you've not provided to bind them all as one question)* there are multiple questions here.

Comment: @Cadence very true, but if our nuclear power plants end up spreading radiation across the world killing vast amounts of wildlife, then whether or not the Yellowstone caldera erupts is less important, no?

Comment: We've long established that asking "What would happen to society if X" is too broad a question for this site. Given the number of environments on this planet your question is similarly broad. Try asking a far more specific question instead. Is there something in particular you're curious about. Ask about that and only that. Your question will be better received and will attract higher caliber answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huge localized damage, less general damage.

## Nuclear power plants aren't designed to be walkaway safe generally, so a lot would melt down and break containment.

Reactors are generally designed to be fairly safe and not cause problems if there's an earthquake or something similar that breaks powerlines, but they're not designed for humans to just abandon them forever, excepting a few smaller reactors and research reactors. A lot would melt down, and so a lot of damage would be done.

## Oil would leak out in a lot of places.

Oil tankers aren't designed to safely go to port on their own, and oil storage facilities need human maintenance. A lot of oil spills would happen and a lot of wildlife would die.

## A lot of dams would break

Dams aren't really designed to have no human maintenance forever. A lot would break and cause environmental damage.

## Global warming would eventually reduce

Initially there would be a spike due to the numerous fires, oil spills, and nuclear melt downs. Eventually though with the lack of humans things would recover.

## A lot of power plants would ignite.

Power plants aren't designed for humans to just leave them forever, so you'd get a lot of burning and accidents.

## A lot of cities would burn.

With no fire engines, a lot of cities would burn, releasing a lot of smog.

## The world is still vulnerable to major disasters.

Humans can do stuff like stop asteroids, which won't happen with humans dead.